# Why do "Inline-Block" elements create a new block formatting context and "Block " elements can't?

Tags: html, css

I understand that inline-block create a new BFC  (block formatting context) but I don't see why this is not given to a block element despite the only difference between the two is "a line break" .

Comment: There are many types of display in html: display, position, text-indent, float, transform, and they were all designed for different benefits. As for why one type doesn't take on the qualities of another is probably moot now but perhaps consult the w3c and Tim Berners Lee to understand the reasons behind such decisions.

Comment: `inline-block` boxes _have_ to establish a BFC for their contents, since there's no way for their contents to participate in any higher ancestor BFC. That's not the case for the contents of regular block boxes, so establishing a BFC or not can be a matter of choice for them.